# Cannot create Compute Instance Microsoft Azure ML

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am new at working with Microsoft Azure and I am trying to open a Notebook from the Azure Machine learning studio. [image]

Every time I try to create a new compute it says **Creation failed** so I cannot work. My region is *francecentral* and I have tried different Virtual Machine size

Answer (score 0):

Your reason might be explained [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/our-commitment-to-customers-and-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/):

> As demand continues to grow, if we are faced with any capacity
>   constraints in any region during this time, we have established clear
>   criteria for the priority of new cloud capacity. Top priority will be
>   going to first responders, health and emergency management services,
>   critical government infrastructure organizational use, and ensuring
>   remote workers stay up and running with the core functionality of
>   Teams.

If you qualify for this category, you should reach out to Azure Support or your Microsoft representative. If not, you need to keep retrying (might work better at night) or try a different region.